# How can I build and install a package and it's dependencies from source using apt?

Tags: debian, apt, powerpc

I am restoring an old iMac G5 which still uses a powerpc processor. Unfortunately, Debian Jessie was the last version of Debian to support Powerpc7. I would like some of the new Stretch packages. I can always compile them from source, but apt won't put source packages in its cache when I do apt-get update. This means I can't download the package or its dependencies.

So my question is, how can I build and install a package and its dependencies from source?

## Edit 1:

I just tried Stephen Kitt's suggestion for running `apt-get update`. Previously, it failed with errors. It recognizes stretch now. I still have trouble getting dependencies though. I think `apt-get build-dep` is trying to download binaries, and failing.

If you want it, my sources.list is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd026fcd3547b5f3fa34726c54fe6836).

Comment: What *does* `apt-get update` do? Have you added Stretch `deb-src` lines? I would have expected the source packages to be downloadable even if binary indexes aren’t available (but I might well be wrong about that!).

Comment: related (including link to an ISO for sid on ppc): https://lists.debian.org/debian-powerpc/2017/06/msg00006.html